# Does this transformation appear to be a rigid motion? Explain

Tags: geometry, rigid-transformation

[image]

Looking at these two examples I believe a an b both would be considered a rigid motion.  A rigid motion is a transformation that preserves distance and angle measures.  Since the image and preimage preserve distance and angle measurments then a and b both would be rigid motions, correct?  I just need to know if my logic is correct to do the other parts of the question.
Thank you!

Comment: Translation , rotation, reflection, and glide reflection are all forms of rigid motion. In this case you are using rotation? To formally think about the problem, you may want to construct a function and see whether such a function falls under the required "rigid motion" categories.

Comment: It varies between sources whether "rigid motions" must preserve handedness. That is, image b (a glide reflection) would be considered a rigid motion under some definitions of that term, but not under others. Sometimes (such as in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_transformation)) a rigid "motion" must preserve handedness (and thus excludes b), whereas a rigid "transformation" only needs to preserve distances.

Comment: No calculations are needed for this particular problem, it's suppose to be just looking at it.  Based on the information presented it seems since their was no change to the size of the figures or angle measurments, then these both would be considered a rigid motion